# Calculate all possible and meaningful permutations

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation, permute

My problem is some kind of the Chinese postman problem.

I got a maze in which the program puts n agents and n targets. Now every agent has to visit every target at least once. Therefore I have to calculate the shortest path between all targets using the A* algorithm, maybe later the D*.

Now my problem is to calculate the permutations of the targets. I mean I have a program which calculates all possible permutations. But this doesn't mean it's clever to know them all. I mean if I have 4 targets, I got n! permutations (in this example 24). But the permutation 1234 got the same path length as 4321. So I need to upgrade my function to find symmetries in all permutations, and just use the A* for the minimum number of permutations.

So this is the code I currently use to generate all permutations. Currently I just print them out, but later i want to sore the permutations in a kind of array or vector, but that's rather simple compared to my main problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  unsigned int n = atoi( argv[1] );
  unsigned int f[n], *const fn = f + sizeof(f) / sizeof(*f);

  for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
  {
    f[j]=(j+1);
  }

  unsigned int i = 0;

  do
  {
    std::cout << ++i << ". Permutation: ";
    copy(f, fn, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));;
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  while(std::next_permutation(f, fn));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be advised that [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) is a non-standard feature, some compilers have it as an extension. If you really want variable length "arrays", then use `std::vector`.

Comment: Also note that while the path from target `1` to `4` is the same as from target `4` to `1` (only reversed), you forget that the *complete* path includes the "agents" traveling to their first target. The path for a specific agent to target `1` will most likely be very different than the path to target `4`.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: I know that the path includes the path for the agent. My approach was: Find the order of the destinations with the shortest path, then examined for each agent the closest target and calculate the way the agent must travel.

Comment: I would do the A* once from each Agent to each target, and from each target to each target: So you have a simple graph. Then your permutation would only do a sum of the edge of the graph.

Comment: @Jarod42: My question is: If I calculate the distance from the first target to all other target, and do this for each target, I just know the distance form on target to an other, but I do not get the shortest rout from a first target above all others, so that all targets are visited

Comment: @user3794592: You may also cache the optimal path in addition to just the distance. The fact is that you don't have to recompute paths for each permutations. (In Addition there are more appropriate algorithms to compute several paths instead of doing A* several time)

Comment: @Jarod42: I think I get what you mean. So first i calculate the distance between form each target to all other targets, so I get a list like this:1->2 500 steps, 1->3 540 steps, 1->4 ... steps; 2->3 ... steps, 2->4 ... steps, 3->4 ... steps. And after that I just calculate the permutation and get the path. But that doesn't solve my problem that there are some permutations that appear twice. And when I got 10 target that means I got about 3.6 million permutations.

Comment: I have add answer to avoid symmetrical permutation. But that divide only by 2 your number of permutations anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To skip symmetrical permutations, you may skip the one where the last node is inferior to first node:

```
void show_permutation(std::vector<unsigned int> v)
{
    int i = 0;
    do {
        if (v.back() < v.front()) {
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << ++i << ". Permutation: ";
        copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/OfX8SG)

Comment: I just tried the code from the live example you just posted. Therefore I added #include <numeric> and #include <vector>, but I still get the error message: [Error] 'iota' is not a member of 'std'.

Comment: `std::iota` is from C++11 in `<numeric>`. If you don't have it, use a normal loop: `for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) { v[i] = i;}`.

Comment: I just tried the code provided by Jarod42. So I tried it with 10 targets, which normally returns 3.628.800 permutations. So with the advanced code I just got 1.814.400 permutations. But it still takes nearly 49 minutes to compute all permutations.

Does anybody have a hint how I can reduce the amount of permutations by more than factor two?